# ¿Obtener día en español de un DateTimePicker?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Es este el código que utilizo para obtener el número de semana, el dia y la fecha.

```
//Se cambia el valor del datepicker para que muestre solamente 
//El año y la semana correspondiente
int x = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
          DPSim.Value, 
          CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, 
          DPSim.Value.DayOfWeek);
//se le asigna el valor a una etiqueta oculta
lblSem.Text = DPSim.Value.Year.ToString() + ", Semana " + x;
//se muestra la etiqueta oculta
lblSem.Visible = true;
//Se obtiene el dia
DPSim.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
string d = DPSim.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString();
lblDiaSim.Text = d;
//Se obtiene la fecha
lblFSim.Text = DPSim.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Si funciona perfecto más al igual soy nuevo y no se como implementarlo en un Windows Form, de igual manera gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 6):

No soy muy conocedor del tema, pero entiendo que se tiene que cambiar la `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` a `CultureInfo("es-ES")`

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime TheDate = DateTime.Parse("January 01 2001");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
        Console.WriteLine(TheDate.ToLongDateString());

    }
}
```

La salida que se obtiene es:

```
lunes, 1 de enero de 2001
```